# How can I replace values matching a certain key in a JSON wrap in a QueryString?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have:

```
queryString=`key_value="something"&type_name=user&value={"password":"Test1234"}&key_attribute=guid`
```

I want to replace the `password` of `Test1234` with `[HIDDEN]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in node, you can just parse and then stringify the query string

```js
var qs=require("querystring")
var temp=qs.parse(queryString)
var user=JSON.parse(temp.value)
user.password='[HIDDEN]'
temp.value=JSON.stringify(user)
queryString=qs.stringify(temp)
```

Browserify have also a querystring implementation, but you also want to use regexp

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve that is:

```js
let queryString=`key_value="something"&type_name=user&value={"password":"Test1234"}&key_attribute=guid`

let modifiedString = queryString.replace(/("password":)"[\w]+"/, '$1"[HIDDEN]"')

console.log(modifiedString)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface to create an iterable object out of the query string. Select the value you want to edit with the [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) method of the object and parse the value to an object using `JSON.parse`.

Now you have the value as an object from which you can update the value of the `password` property.

Use the [`set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) method to overwrite the `value` entry of the query string and stringify the object back to JSON.

Turn the URLSearchParams object back to a string with the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString) method.

```js
const queryString=`key_value="something"&type_name=user&value={"password":"Test1234"}&key_attribute=guid`;
const params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const value = params.get('value');
const objectValue = JSON.parse(value);

objectValue.password = '[HIDDEN]';
params.set('value', JSON.stringify(objectValue));

const updatedQueryString = params.toString();
console.log(updatedQueryString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Altho there are bunch of packages that can be used to fix this, I suggest learning how to solve it raw

Below solutions will help to understand how to make things

```js
const queryString = `key_value="something"&type_name=user&value={"password":"Test1234"}&key_attribute=guid`;


// SOLUTION 1
// convert string to object, change key, and convert back to string
const jsonString = queryString
  .split('&')
  .reduce((acc, next) => {
    const [key, value] = next.split('=');
    acc[key] = value.indexOf('{') === 0 ? JSON.parse(value) : value;
    return acc
  }, {})

jsonString.value.password = '[HIDDEN]'

const solution1 = Object.keys(jsonString).map(key => {
  const val = typeof jsonString[key] === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(jsonString[key]) : jsonString[key]
  return `${key}=${val}`

}).join('&')



// SOLUTION 2
// Simply replace by regex using strict parameter
const solution2 = queryString.replace(/&value={"password":"(\w+)"}&/gi, '[HIDDEN]')

console.log('Using JSON.parse:', solution1)
console.log('Using regex:', solution2)
```